# Is it possible to re-route FCM's In-App Messaging popup?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am using Firebase's In-App Messaging SDK. So when I run a campaign, it's shows the popup into my Launcher screen of the application.

But instead of that I want to show into the Home screen of the application. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean when you say home screen and launcher screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use a scheduler in the firebase console for that. You can specify after which event the FIAM should appear. On the screenshot below, I have added two events: `on_foreground` and `open_profile_tab`. The first one is added by default.
Please notice, that the FIAM will be displayed after `ANY` of these events occur.

[image: In app messaging schedule option]